# git clone repo A to new repo B while still getting updates from repo A

Tags: git

I'm using electron-react-boilerplate. It instructs installing by cloning the repo:

```
git clone --depth 1 --single-branch https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate.git your-project-name
```

I want to be able to modify this local git and have it stored in my own repository.
For this I created a new repository:

```
git remote add my_remote_repo https://github.com/paragbaxi/my_remote_repo
```

I track those changes in local branches that i store in my remote repo

```
git checkout -b local_branch
git commit -a -m 'Initial commit'
git push my_remote_repo local_branch
```

How do I pull in changes from the origin (electron-react-boilerplate) to merge them in safely?

Option 1: By creating a local branch and merging?

1. Create local branch

   ```
    git checkout -b branch_to_pull_from_erb
   ```
2. Merge

   ```
    git merge origin
   ```

Option 2: By pulling against origin?

1. Pull from erb

   ```
    git pull https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate.git
   ```

Other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

`git checkout -b some_remote_branchname`

`git pull origin some_remote_branchname`

Then you can merge `some_remote_branchname` and `local_branch`.

Alternatively, if you want to pull the remote branch into a local brach with a different name, you can pull like this:

`git pull origin some_remote_branchname:some_local_branchname`